# How to build a dynamic list in Flutter?

Tags: listview, asynchronous, flutter

I have this widget attached to a `Scaffold` body. The widget gets a `async` method that returns a json object.

I want to build a list, dynamically, from that json object. The problem is that the screen is empty.. For some reason this widget needs to refresh itself when the list is ready or something like that.

Any ideas?

```
class TestList extends StatelessWidget {
  final quiz;

  TestList({this.quiz});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var listArray = [];

    this.quiz.then((List value) {   // this is a json object

      // loop through the json object
      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {

        // add the ListTile to an array
        listArray.add(new ListTile(title: new Text(value[i].name));

      }
    });

    return new Container(
        child: new ListView(
      children: listArray     // add the list here.
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `setState` to rebuild the UI.

Example:

```
class TestList extends StatefulWidget {

  final Future<List> quiz;

  TestList({this.quiz});

  @override
  _TestListState createState() => new _TestListState();

}

class _TestListState extends State<TestList> {

  bool loading = true;

  _TestListState(){
    widget.quiz.then((List value) {

      // loop through the json object
      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {

        // add the ListTile to an array
        listArray.add(new ListTile(title: new Text(value[i].name));

        }

            //use setState to refresh UI
            setState((){
          loading = false;
        });

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> listArray = [];

    return new Container(
        child: new ListView(
            children: loading?[]:listArray     // when the state of loading changes from true to false, it'll force this widget to reload
        ));

  }

}
```

Comment: `setState() isn't defined for the class TestList` hmm

Comment: Make your TestList as StatefulWidget. Wait I sec, I'll edit my answer to implement a StatefulWidget.

Comment: I think `setState((){ loading = false; });` might need to be set outside the loop

Comment: Yeah, tho definitely some weirdness. If I comment out `setState()`, `loading` is false inside the `widget.quiz.then..`, unless I move `bool loading = true;` just above it.

Comment: and `setState(() { loading = false; });` inside the `widget.quiz.then..` does an infinite loop for some reason. Maybe some scoping issues..

Comment: Yeah sorry, you need to move the whole `widget.quiz.then....` to the constructor. That happens because `setState` calls the build method, thus again the `widget.quiz.then..` is called.

Comment: How would that look like? You mean the `TestList` constructor ? How would I set do the loop there and pass the data to the list?

Comment: Edited the answer!

Comment: I managed to make it work. `widget.quiz` is not available, but If i pass it through like: `new _CreateList(quiz: this.quiz)` then I can get use it.

Comment: Passing widgets is not advised.You can also look into [initState](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) method of StatefulWidget.

Answer (score 7):

You can use FutureBuilder to help with the widget states:

```
new FutureBuilder<List>(
  future: widget.quiz,
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return new Text('Waiting to start');
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return new Text('Loading...');
      default:
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          return new ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  new Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length);
        }
    }
  },
)
```

Basically, it notifies the method specified on builder depending on the future state. Once the future received a value and is not an error, you can use ListView.builder to make the list, this is a convenience method to create the list when all items are of the same type.

More info at https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Though your answer is more adheres to Async standar i dont know why i was getting multiple call and snapshot.hasError was getting executed, ListBuilder never got executed